# Setup sending post request from android to php script

Tags: php, android, post, retrofit2

Android Retrofit's servise interface:

```
//@Headers("Authorization: " + BuildConfig.CLIENT_NAME + " " + BuildConfig.CLIENT_PASSWORD)
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("api/post/report")
Observable<Object> postReport(@Field("message") String message);
```

Android monitor tells:

```
--> POST http://<mysite>/api/post/report http/1.1
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 104
D/OkHttp: message=%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%3A%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%87%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%B6%D1%8B
D/OkHttp: --> END POST (104-byte body)
```

I do not know how to catch the Message from PHP.

$_POST - is empty

```
parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $data);
$data = (object)$data;
```

Different variants of ^ are also not working. They returns nullable results, empty objects and ext

Answer (score 0):

You are making a `POST` request.

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Should give you the value sent from `retrofit`.

Comment: Ok then debug it

Comment: Returns Array (
)

Comment: Try with  `$_REQUEST`, if it is still empty then the issue is the android app

Answer (score 0):

Ok.ok. I did this:

```
//@Headers("Authorization: " + BuildConfig.CLIENT_NAME + " " +    BuildConfig.CLIENT_PASSWORD)
@POST("api/post/report")
Observable<Object> postReport(@Header("message") String message);
```

I sent this via Header & catched the message with getHeaders() method...